# Show that any four polynomials in $P_2$ (the space of polynomials of at most degree 2) are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that any four polynomials in $P_2$ (the space of polynomials of at most degree 2) are linearly dependent.

I think somehow in matrix form it will have 4 rows and 3 columns and something about that might show they're linearly dependent but as you can probably gather I'm a bit lost. I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: The space of polynomials of at most degree 2

Comment: Ok. Do you know its dimension?

Comment: I feel like it's 3 but I don't know how to show that it's 3

Comment: Do you know a basis for this space?

Comment: Is it $\{1,x,x^2\}$?

Comment: Yes: thus $\dim P_2=\text{card}\{1,x,x^2\}=3$. Now see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a linearly independent family of vectors of a space $V$ has necessarily a number of vectors less than $\dim V$.

**Other approach:** if you put your vectors as rows in a matrix, then they are independent iff the rank of this matrix is the number of vectors of the family (i.e. The number of rows of the matrix). Now a $4\times 3$ matrix has rank $\leq 3$ thus your vectors are necessarily dependent.

**Edit:** In my other approach, I used the theorem stating that a $m\times n$ matrix has rank $\leq \min(m,n)$.

Comment: Does what you've stated in "Other approach" come from a theorem?

Comment: Yes. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of $P_2$ is 3 as you said. if you have **4** polynomials in $P_2$ that are independent, then the space should have a dimension of 4. This is not true. By contradiction, the 4 polynomials are linear dependent.